# RPI Not Booting because of infinite shell script

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, sh, infinite-loop, boot

so today i was trying to get a shell script(which is an infinite loop) to run on boot in the background of my RaspberryPi's terminal.

I used this command:  update-rc.d -f GPIOServer.sh start 4
and then rebooted my pi and after a couple seconds it runs the infinite loop and doesn't boot to the terminal.

i don't know how to cancel the script: ive tried ^C ^Z ^X Esc  and i dont want to have to erase all my files etc.

Please help.

Comment: Why can't you just pull out the SD card, mount it on another machine, and make the changes there?

Answer (score 1):

There are several options to get a shell without completing the full boot process:

1. Try switching to a different console for example with `CTRL+ALT+F2` (or any other F2-12 key). This will only work if your init script is one of the last scripts to start.
2. If the ssh server started before your script then you will be able to connect remotely from another computer
3. Follow Ignacio's recommendation: by taking out the SD card and mounting the SD card on another linux computer and deleting your init script
4. If you only have a mac or windows machine then you will only be able to edit the boot parition of the SD card. In this case you can modify/add the boot config file `cmdline.txt` to boot straight into a root terminal. If there is already a `cmdline.txt` file on the the sd-card then make a **backup copy** of this file and then simply add `init=/bin/bash` after the `root` kernel parameter.

   For example, the full line might look something like this:

   `dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 kgdboc=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p3 init=/bin/bash rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait`

   If there is no `cmdline.txt` file on the sd-card then create a new empty text file and just put `init=/bin/bash` into that file. Your raspberry pi will now boot straight into a root terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not logging in as root. You can try to log in as root and disable the infinite loop for your user's shell.

Comment: It's not getting to the point where the asker can even log in in the first place.